# Filter out ABC characters, numeric 123 and special characters out of input string using bash scripting

Tags: awk, cut

I want to take string input from user and do some bash processing to filter out ABC characters in one file, 123 numeric values in another file and @#$ special characters in another file.

**Input string:** `ABCD1234!@#`

Output:

```
cat file1.txt: ABCD 
cat file2.txt: 1234
cat file3.txt: !@#
```

I tried certain cut and awk commands but didn't find any solution. Found many solutions in other languages but not in bash.

```
echo "abc123#@" | tr -dc '0-9' && echo "abc123#@" | tr -dc 'a-z'
```

I cannot extract all special characters from it. Also how to from one command. or bash script? if my question makes sense

Comment: @anubhava  echo "abc123#@" | tr -dc '0-9' && echo "abc123#@" | tr -dc 'a-z'
I cannot extract all special characters from it. Also how to from one command. or bash script? if my question makes sense.

Comment: What if input string is `@ABCD1234PQR!@#78`? What should be in file1, file2 and file3?

Comment: @anubhava sir. the ABC or alphabet characters in file one, numbers in file2 and special characters in file 3. 
file 1: ABCDPQR file2: 123478 file3: @!@#.
If I didn't miss any character in string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single `awk` command for this:

```sh
str='ABCD1234!@#'

awk '{
   p = q = r = $0
   gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]+/, "", p)
   gsub(/[^[:digit:]]+/, "", q)
   gsub(/[[:alnum:]]+/, "", r)
   print p > "file1.txt"
   print q > "file2.txt"
   print r > "file3.txt"
}' <<< "$str"
```

Comment: Oh wow. This is cool. Also, I tried to change *print p > "file1.txt"* into print q, print $q. Can this code display the results on terminal or I shall have to make a different script for that? Please guide me sir.

Comment: It can print on terminal, use: `print p, q, r`